# Mongo aggregation match expression and partial Indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, match, aggregation

I've been testing partial indexes on Mongo, and it seems the use of an [aggregation expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions) in the `$match` stage interferes with using the correct index.

For example, I have a `data` collection with the following docs:

```
{
    "type": "person",
    "value": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "age": 10
    }
},
{
    "type": "person",
    "value": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Person 2",
        "age": 20
    }
}
```

And I create a partial index for `{"type": "person"}` documents. When I run the aggregation

```
{
    "$match": {
        "type": "person",
        "value.age": { "$gte": 15 }
    }
}
```

the index registers a hit, but if I do the next aggregation it doesn't.

```
{
    "$match": {
        "$expr": {
            "$and": [
                { "$eq": ["$type", "person"] },
                { "$gte": ["$value.age", 15] },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Are partial indexes and aggregation expressions in `$match` incompatible? Is there any way I can make this work?

PS: I need to use aggregation expressions because I'm making `$lookup` with the let and pipeline [syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries).

Answer (score 0):

> You can use

```js
{
    "$match": {
         "$and": [
                {"type": "person" },
                {"value.age": {"$gte":15}},
         ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the equivalent of the first aggregation in my question. I'm aware I can do that, but that doesn't use [aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions).
Edited question to clarify